# Floor function parity problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, parity

Prove that for every natural k this expression is always odd $⌊(5+\sqrt{19})^k⌋=A^k$
Progress that I' ve done is:
I noticed $9^k<A^k<(9.5)^k$
Also I tried an induction approach, I used Binomial theorem, I rewrote the expression as $⌊(9+(\sqrt{19}-4))^k⌋$. But so far none of this approaches lead me to anything.
Could you give me some tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For all integers $k \ge 0$,

$$f(k) = (5 + \sqrt{19})^k + (5 - \sqrt{19})^k \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

is an integer. You can fairly easily prove this using something like the binomial theorem, where the pairing of terms also gives useful parity information. In addition, note $0 \lt 5 - \sqrt{19} \lt 1$.

Comment: I don't see how does it help solving this problem. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: @somerndguy You can prove $f(k)$ is always an even integer due to, when you expand $(5 + \sqrt{19})^k$  and $(5 - \sqrt{19})^k$ and combine the terms with the same powers of $\sqrt{19}$, the terms with odd powers of $\sqrt{19}$ cancel and the terms with even powers of $\sqrt{19}$ are integers and are doubled up. You also have $\left\lfloor (5 + \sqrt{19})^k \right\rfloor = f(k) - 1$.

Comment: I see that for $k=2n$ and $k=2n+1$ $A^k=2(5^{2n}+5^{2n-2}(\sqrt{19})^2+...+(\sqrt{19})^{2n})$ and $A^k=2(5^{2n+1}+5^{2n-1}(\sqrt{19})^2+...+(\sqrt{19})^{2n+1})$ but can't understand how does it refer to $A^{k}=f(k)-1$. Could you be more specific.

Comment: @somerndguy Since $0 \lt 5 - \sqrt{19} \lt 1$, you have $0 \lt (5 - \sqrt{19})^k \lt 1$ for all positive integers $k$. Since $(5 + \sqrt{19})^k = f(k) - (5 - \sqrt{19})^k$, this means $f(k) - 1 \lt (5 + \sqrt{19})^k \lt f(k)$, so since $f(k)$ is an integer, you have $\left\lfloor (5 + \sqrt{19})^k \right\rfloor = f(k) - 1$. Finally, note that in your comment above for the second $A^k$ expression, the coefficient of the $(\sqrt{19})^{2n+1})$ term at the end is actually $0$.